Import nest-mqtt inside Nest.js
I want to create an MQTT conection based on Configuration module in my Nest.js app. I am using very old npm package: https://github.com/microud/nest-mqtt . I updated necessary dependencies and now I try to use it. However i am experiencing this issue:
Error: Nest cant resolve dependencies of the MQTT_OPTION_PROVIDER (?). Please make sure that the argument ConfigurationService at index [0] is available in the MqttModule context.

Here is how my app.module looks:
@Module({
  imports: [ConfigurationModule, MySQLModule, MQTTModule],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule {}

config.module.ts
@Module({
  imports: [ConfigModule.forRoot()],
  providers: [ConfigurationService],
  exports: [ConfigurationService],
})
export class ConfigurationModule {}

mqtt.module.ts
const MqttGlobalConnection = MqttModule.forRootAsync({
  useFactory: (config: ConfigurationService) => ({
    logger: {
      useValue: new CustomLogger('MQTT'),
    },
    ...config.MQTT_GLOBAL_CONNECTION,
  }),
  inject: [ConfigurationService],
  imports: [ConfigurationModule],
});

@Module({
  imports: [ConfigurationModule, MqttGlobalConnection],
})
export class MQTTModule {}

Is something incorrect in this pretty simple configuration or the error is in the nest-mqtt library.
PS
When i changed forRootAsync into forRoot everything seems to work, but looks a little bit worse in my opinion:
const MqttGlobalConnection = MqttModule.forRoot({
  logger: { useValue: new CustomLogger('MQTT') },
  ...new ConfigurationService(new ConfigService()).MQTT_GLOBAL_CONNECTION,
});


run npm ls @nestjs/core to see if you got multiple versions of @nestjs/core installed because that package has a peer dep on @nestjs/core <=v8

It is 10.3 only. I have downloaded the source code of package and pasted into into my project, so it uses same npm packages now.

The problem was in the package itself. I've compared it with other package that i'm using and found something. Inside the package in forRootAsync method the "import" line were missing.
public static forRootAsync(options: MqttModuleAsyncOptions): DynamicModule {
    return {
      module: MqttModule,
      providers: [
        ...createOptionProviders(options),
        createLoggerProvider(options),
        createClientProvider(),
        MqttExplorer,
        MqttService,
      ],
      imports: options.imports || [],
    };
  }

Once i`ve added it, everything started working properly.
